# Am i excused if i cant keep najasah away from my clothes and body?

Tags: hadith, fiqh, sharia, allah, taharah

Salam,

I have sickness called urine incontinence that makes me urinate involuntarily when I move or even stay still. When i go to the toilet, i do istinja with water but immediately after pouring the water i urinate. And also when i get up from my sitting position in the toilet i urinate, and it gets on my clothes and body. No matter how hard i try to prevent it, i just cant. i need to get up to get the water necessary to clean myself. this whole process takes me between 20min and 30min which is very exhausting. Am I excused for this because i cant prevent the urine from getting on my body and clothes ? jazakum allahu khayran, please also give scholarly proof if you have an answer